# Given a differential function such as: $y''+z_1 y'+z_2 y=0$, when can we assume that $z_1,z_2 \in \mathbb R$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Take the differential equation:
$$y''+z_1 y'+z_2 y=0$$

Its characteristic polynomial is $r^2+z_1 r+ z_2=0$. Its roots are: $$r_{1,2} = \frac{-z_1\pm \sqrt {z_1^2 - 4 z_2}} {2}$$

However, this is only true if we assume $z_1,z_2$ to be real numbers.

My question is:
Can we assume that?

If not, how do we find the roots in the case $z_1,z_2 \in \mathbb C$

If yes, why is it so? I mean, we do allow the roots to be complex.

Maybe in the case of "real diferential functions" we talk about:
$$T:C^2(\mathbb C) \longrightarrow C(\mathbb R)$$
and in the case of "complex differential functions" we talk about:
$$T:C^2(\mathbb C) \longrightarrow C(\mathbb C)$$

Somehow, from what i see, it is never explicitely mentioned..
(feels like.. am I the only one whom which this is not clear to?)

**Edit**:
My problem in the complex case is that it is much harder to say things on the solutions if $z_1,z_2$ are unknown parameters (am I right?). For example, I want to know if $$ lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac {y(x)}{e^x} = 0 $$ for $x \rightarrow \infty$. Given $z_1,z_2 \in \mathbb R$. I can figure out the real part assuming $z_i \lessgtr 0$ etc. How do I do that if $z_1,z_2 \in \mathbb R$?

Comment: The same quadratic formula holds for complex numbers too. You just interpret $\sqrt{z}$ as one of the complex numbers whose square is $z$. And for the purposes of finding roots only, a particular choice of branch is not needed either.

Comment: Indeed the quadratic formula holds for any field of characteristic not equal to $2$

Comment: What do your $T:C^2(\mathbb C) \longrightarrow C(\mathbb R)$ and $T:C^2(\mathbb C) \longrightarrow C(\mathbb C)$ denote?

Comment: @peek-a-boo, Thank you for your comment. What does it mean "a choice of a branch"?

Comment: A choice of a domain $U$ in the complex plane and a continuous (or holomorphic) function $f:U\to\Bbb{C}$ such that for each $z\in U$, we have $[f(z)]^2=z$. Essentially it amounts to choosing the $\pm$ consistently to produce a holomorphic function. Anyway, you can ignore this mumbo jumbo for your question. All you need is that for every non-zero complex number there are exactly two complex numbers whose square is the original guy.

Comment: Please OP, can you answer my question of 10 hours ago?